# Email Alert in workflow on multiple records

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

We have an object related to Contacts called "Storage".  We store products for our customers for x amount of time and record this within this object.  When the field "Stored Date" is 30 days in the passed we want to automatically email the contact to alert them that fees will apply soon.  This is usually really straight forward with a simple workflow rule/formula and email alert.

My problem is that a customer can store dozens of products with us and they may all breach this deadline at the same time.  I only want to email the customer once.  Is there a way to restrict the email or something like that?

I was thinking of adding an "email" field, update it when the workflow rule is triggered but considering dozens of products may breach at the same time I don't know if it would work?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkbox 'Email Sent' or something similar and restrict to only fire workflow when checkbox is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this would be a good use case for the new [Scheduled Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_start.htm&type=5). You could use the flow to fetch all the items related to a Contact that have breached on the current date, and then send one email per contact with all the items.

Comment: This needs some elaboration; what would the scheduled flow's filter look like? If it is on Contact, then some risk of exceeding limits